# Master-master database replication on 5 servers

Tags: replication, clustering, redis

My current project requires immediate replication between 5 databases. Servers are physically distributed across the globe. Currently we use Redis with one master server installed on another 6th server. All database writes on any of 5 servers are performed to this 6th master server, and other 5 are slaves of it. This approach has a lot of flaws and i'm looking for solution to replace it. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just throwing this out there but have you thought of using a MQ for writes?

We're using RabbitMQ for writes and federating it out to multiple data centers where each one has a flexihash cluster of ~20 Redis servers. So far it's working well for us and you can increase or decrease the size of each cluster independently as long as your rebalancing them appropriately. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is the best approach for me! It doesn't requires database engine change!